# Can't access OpenMary TTS from Azure endpoint

Tags: java, iis, marytts

I just deployed an instance of `OpenMary TTS server` on my `Windows 2012 Azure VM` and configured ttp endpoints for both port `80` and the default `59125` ports. I've tried launching mary server using both ports and I can't access it externally using either the DNS name or the external IP. I installed IIS on the same host and I am able to access the default page remotely so I know it is not an Azure configuration issue, rather something in OpenMary causing it to only accept requests coming from the loopback IP or localhost.

Is there a hostname setting I can supply on the cmd line via java property? I can change its port name via `-Dsocket.port=` setting but how do I tweak the host name it listens on? Does it make sense to set the server up behind IIS?

Answer (score 0):

in the Windows Azure Portal, you need to configure the end point mapping.

Comment: Yes I've configured the end point mapping from the portal. I believe the problem is actually related to OpenMary server. I believe there is a host configuration setting somewhere but I've not been able to find it.